# Canvas image not appearing in IE10 and below

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

No idea what I'm doing wrong here, but apparently I've upset IE10 somehow. I've got a bit of FabricJS that looks simple enough. It works in everything except IE10 and below. Not sure why?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240,240,240)'
});

var imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSource');
var fabricImg = new fabric.Image(
    imgElement, {
        selectable: false,
        evented: false,
        hasControls: false,
        hasBorders: false
     }
);

canvas.add(fabricImg);
```

Screenshot showing IE10 (left) and IE11 (right):

[image]

Demo (open in < IE11 to see the problem): https://jsfiddle.net/8fy3rv04/

I've tweaked every option I can think of and looked through the [FabricJS documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html) for `fabric.Image`, but I can't see where I might have done something to anger IE. Pulling my hair out now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a simple bit of CSS that marked `imageSource` as `display:none`. It was useful to load the image in a hidden `<img>` element and then put it on the canvas, but instead I've had to load the image through `fabric.Image.fromURL`.

A very weird issue for IE10 that meant as the `<img>` was hidden, so was the image when it was put on the canvas! Bizarre.